# Toggling with variables in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, database, toggle

```
$last_itteration = false;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        if ($row['egenskaps_navn'] == $last_itteration) {

        } else {
            echo "<h3>".$row['egenskaps_navn']."</h3>";             
        }
        echo "<span id='verdi_"  .$row['verdi_id']."'>".$row['verdi_tekst']."</span><br />";

        $last_itteration = $row['egenskaps_navn'];

    }


$(document).ready(function(){

 $('h3').click(function(){
  $('span').toggle();   
});
```

I have collected data from a database. The idea is that I want to toggle values to show from a list of properties (marked h3). The while loop only prints a property if it already hasnt been printed and the connected values. They are currently hidden in the CSS with "span {display: none;}". Now the toggle will only work for all the values and not the connected ones. Is there a similar way to do it in jquery or javascript as i have done it in the PHP code? To select only one property (h3) for toggling since i don't want to toggel them all at once.

Comment: You could use `this` with `nextUntil('h3')` to toggle everything between the clicked `h3` and the next `h3`: [`$(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();`](http://jsfiddle.net/k263m6fz/)

Comment: `$('h3').click(function(){ $(this).find('span').toggle(); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextUntil('h3')` to toggle everything between the clicked `h3` and the next `h3`:

```
$('h3').on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').toggle();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k263m6fz/)

Comment: Since you were first ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Find the next `span` of the current `h3` on `click` event on `h3` and apply the `toggle` to it. Try with -

```
$('h3').click(function(){
   $(this).next('span').toggle();   
});
```

Comment: While this code is useful, a few words of explanation would make it a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

This triggers the closest span to the h3 clicked

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('h3').click(function(){
    $(this).next('span').toggle();   
  });
});
```

or as billyonecan mentioned:

```
 $(this).nextUntil('h3','span').toggle();
```

the second argument makes the function select only the spans